# Is there a way to get symbol information with ${}

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get the symbol information the cursor is at with `${...}` from `tasks.json` in vscode? [image: Screenshot]
I can get the line number with `${lineNumber}`, but that's not good enough for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the extensions [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by), [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) and [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) you can construct a command that searches for the first `public` backwards, search forward and select for `Test\w+(?=\()` then call the task you want with [workbench.action.tasks.runTask](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_binding-keyboard-shortcuts-to-tasks). In the task you can use the variable `extension.commandvariable.selectedText` to get the name of the Test the cursor is in.